# "property has a previous declaration" error in class extension: bug or feature?

Tags: objective-c, clang, xcode10

In Objective-C you can *generally* re-declare a `readonly` property as `readwrite` in a class extension like this:

```
@interface PubliclyImmutablePrivatelyMutableClass : NSObject

@property (readonly, nonatomic) SomeStateEnum someState;

@end

// In "PubliclyImmutablePrivatelyMutableClass+Private.h"
// or "PubliclyImmutablePrivatelyMutableClass.m"
@interface PubliclyImmutablePrivatelyMutableClass()

@property (readwrite, nonatomic) SomeStateEnum someState;

@end

// In "PubliclyImmutablePrivatelyMutableClass.m"
@implementation PubliclyImmutablePrivatelyMutableClass @end
```

If, however, I introduce a property in a class extension as `readonly` and try to re-declare it as `readwrite` in a second one, Xcode 10’s Clang gives me a compiler error:

```
@interface ClassWithPrivateImmutableInternallyMutableProperty : NSObject

// any public API

@end


// In "ClassWithPrivateImmutableInternallyMutableProperty+Private.h"
@interface ClassWithPrivateImmutableInternallyMutableProperty()

@property (readonly, nonatomic) SomePrivateStateEnum somePrivateState;

@end


// In "ClassWithPrivateImmutableInternallyMutableProperty.m"
@interface ClassWithPrivateImmutableInternallyMutableProperty()

@property (readwrite, nonatomic) SomePrivateStateEnum somePrivateState; // error: property has a previous declaration

@end

@implementation ClassWithPrivateImmutableInternallyMutableProperty
// other API
@end
```

Now I wonder:

- Is the compiler error a bug/regression in Clang or a deliberate feature?
- If it’s a bug, is there another workaround than manually implementing the setter?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is correct behavior from the compiler.

In the second example you are using two class continuation categories with the same name `()` to declare the same property on two occasions. It is effectively the same as declaring the same property name twice in the same extension.

Note that this differs from the first example, in which the property is declared first in the *header* and then re-declared in a single class continuation category named `()`.

If I am right, then the answer is to mark the '+private' class extension with a name like `(Private)` instead of `()`:

```
@interface ClassWithPrivateImmutableInternallyMutableProperty(Private)
```

And also if you have any implementation for the private extension:

```
@implementation ClassWithPrivateImmutableInternallyMutableProperty(Private)
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: If you put a name into the parentheses, it’s not a class continuation anymore: it becomes a plain old category, and those behave differently from class continuations (no auto synthesis of properties, no way of adding instance variables, for example).

Comment: If you want to use two class continuations then you cannot declare a property with the same name in both. Maybe use an internal name in the implementation like `_somePrivateState` and then provide a getter in the +private class continuation that exposes that backing property `- (SomePrivateEnum)somePrivateState`.